# Ошибка Pycharm после "экстренной переустановки"

Tags: python, pycharm, библиотеки

Шалом, появилась проблема с загрузкой библиотек и запуском пайчарма после переустановки.
История такова, что мне пришлось чистить файлы компа и я случайно снёс Pycharm без унинстайлера. Теперь при запуске мне пишется это:

```
File C:\Users\ilyaM\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is di
sabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

А при импорте библеотек, которые были в коде, который до этого работал:

```
C:\Users\ilyaM\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ilyaM/PycharmProjects/Pygame/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ilyaM\PycharmProjects\Pygame\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

(по факту стандартная ошибка, прога просто не видит библу, но почему?)

Comment: Вообще то он пишет что исполнение PowerShell скриптов запрещено, поэтому он не может активировать окружение. (а так возьмите за правило .venv в папке проекта размещать)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь